# remove the /32 from ip string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to remove the /32 from a list of IPs
The list is export with 14 columns.
The IP address is in column 9 & 11

I tried with sed: `sed 's_/32__' filename`
but this leaves a large amount of x.x.x.x/32 lines left.
like;172.16.16.160/32;22;TCP

So I was thinking of using awk to select column 9 & 11 and pipe it thru sed, but this ends up in a mess and errors.

Just cut everything behind a / will not work, since there are also urls in the list.

Any help would be appreciated.

An (anonymized) data sample below where sed already ran on:

```
timestamp (UTC);ID;Threat Level;Category;Exporter IP address;Observation domain ID (ODID);Source MAC;Manufacturer;Source IP;Source Port;Destination IP;Destination Port;Protocol;Description
2020-03-14 13:54:10;20810;5;Ingress Traffic;::ffff:ac8:c8d0/128;101;00:10:8c:f0:cx:c0;Intel;8.8.8.8/32;49420;10.0.0.1/32;22;TCP;Ingress connection to common SSH port:  100% CertaintyHigh Severity Category: SSH Description: Shh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may accomplish this with `awk` only:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {sub(/\/32/, "", $9);sub(/\/32/, "", $11);}1' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/h1W5jV)

**Details**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}` - sets input and output field separator to `;`
- `sub(/\/32/,"", $9);sub(/\/32/,"", $11);` - remove first instances of `/32` from Field 9 and 11
- `1` - triggers default print action.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution you are using only substitutes the first occurrence. You have more than one occurrence in each line, so you will have to do another substitution like the previous one or, easier, do a global substitution:

```
sed 's_/32__g' filename
```

In any case, take into account that these substitutions act on the whole file, not only on the contents of columns 9 and 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
gawk '{gsub("/32",""); print}' file
```

gsub removes all occurences of /32 on the entire input record ($0) and print outputs it.